# Cannot print/save image generated by System.Drawing and Response.OutputStream

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with **printing/saving** images I create during execution of webpage and send to browser via Response.OutputStream.

I have this simple function:

```
 private void makepng()
 {            
        // INFO: the MyBitmapFile bitmap is created here, and then streamed to browser below:

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "image/png";

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            MyBitmapFile.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        }
        Response.End();
 }
```

It also shows the image in the browser, but you can't print or right click on the image and save

- If I do so I get a pop-up error that says "The file type being saved or retrieved has been blocked."
- If I call the `makepng()` as the only thing in the `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`, then all works and I can print/save.
- But if I call it in a button click, then the images is shown, but I can't print/save it - and get the error above.

I think the problem is with the postback the button do, but I don't know how to get it work.

Comment: Maybe you should add a file name? `Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.png");`

Comment: The length, too. `Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", ms.Length.ToString());`

Comment: After the statement `MyBitmapFile.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);` insert the following: `ms.Position = 0;`. You need to rewind the memory stream otherwise it will write nothing to the output stream.

Comment: Thanks to all 3 possible solutions above. The first with setting a filename actually works, but the browser will download the file, which also works nice - but the image is not displayed in the browser. But I can live with it, then the users just have to save the file before viewing. The other 2 solutions don’t work.